# Can I use JS to download a csv file?

Tags: javascript

I am building a little stock tracker for myself.

I currently go to yahoo finance for my spreadsheet information.
Like this: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/spy/history?p=spy

The download link looks something like this: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/SPY?period1=1553009815&period2=1555688215&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=G8A7kw..l2X

Currently, I manually download the spreadsheet data and parse it with JS in my code.

I was wondering if it possible to cut out the manual downloading and instead, use JS to create the link, and download that information, then parse it all together.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, you can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: There may be CORS issues, you may need to pass that URL through a proxy like cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com.

Comment: Haha dealing with that now. @NoahB